# React native Sim infomation

Tags: android, ios, react-native

How to get sim information(need carrier) in react-native both Android & IOS. I found out about this topic but I didn't find a proper way to do this. 
Please help.

Comment: check npm, I've published a package there as `react-native-sim-data`

Comment: Thanks @pocesar. I'll check it.